# Store onclick event in browser with jQuery Cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cookies

I'm working on a newsfeed of posts that on click filters out the the type of content listed.

```
<div class="option all"    onclick="Stories('all',0);"></div>
<div class="option photos" onclick="Stories('photos',0);"></div>
<div class="option videos" onclick="Stories('videos',0);"></div>      
<div class="option music"  onclick="Stories('music',0);"></div>
```

This is the code i use to customize css style for each button and save it.

```
$('.option').eq($.cookie('active')).addClass('clicked');
$(".option").click(function (e) {
    $.cookie('active', $('.option').index(this));
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass("clicked");
    $(".option").not(this).removeClass("clicked");
});
```

How can i store the "onclick" event with jquery.cookie.js? On browser reload the default "all" shows but I would want the last "onclick" option of posts to show instead and not just the css style so I need a way to save the "onclick"

Answer (score 2):

I recommend use **`localStorage`** instead a **cookie**:

You can handle `localStorage` easy without any library and is supported in all modern browsers (IE8 +):

```
localStorage.setItem('lastClicked', 'Your value here'); //save
localStorage.getItem('lastClicked'); //retrieve
```

Check out the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions/XUL_School/Local_Storage).

Here is the [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage).

**[Update] - Integrating code with click event**

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('.clicked').click(function(){
    localStorage.setItem('lastClicked', this); //replace this for whatever you want to store
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi, I don't fully understand how I can use this to record the click of the div, most of the info i've come across mention keys and values or for use in a form.

Comment: @Dennis can you give me an example of something you want to store?

Comment: All i want to do is trigger a click event on the page or at least save the last click on the element with the class .clicked 
[code]
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.clicked').trigger('click'); 
});
[code]

Comment: @Dennis I don't know if it is what you want but please check the answer. I have edited with a new code.

Comment: Okay just tried it, but when I check Chrome console LocalStorage i don't see anything saved. My website is ajax and when I navigate away from the links and back the click is not be utilized. How can i check to see if it working?